# Spring boot - i18n error messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization

When using Spring boot with a simple rest api and for some reason I get an error, it comes in english, like this:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date] for value '2018-07-35'; nested exception is org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Cannot parse \"2018-07-35\": Value 35 for dayOfMonth must be in the range [1,31]"
```

Is it possible to translate all these spring boot messages based on the request locale?

Comment: What does i18n have to do with conversion of string to date? Anyway no month has  35 days.

Comment: Please read  cause of error, before asking

Comment: The problem is not the content of the message. The question is about the internationalization of error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spring often the important part of error log is at the end of message:

```
Value 35 for dayOfMonth must be in the range [1,31]"
```

Are you trying to create months longer?

I did't perfeclty read your question, sorry.

You cannot translate in your local the stack trace, that wolud mean that you need to know all possible messages of native and library functions and then create some translate file.

However using try and catch you can catch some exception and print a custom message:

```
 public void parseDate(String string){
        try{
            Date date = Date.parse(string);
        }catch(IllegalFieldValueException e){
            System.err.println("Date " + string + "is invalid in your local");
        }
    }
```

I used casual calls here to do a simple example.

But spring not always you can do that, so GlobalExceptionHandler is your friend, here an example from my project code:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandlerController.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(UsernameNotFoundException.class)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity usernameNotFound(UsernameNotFoundException e) {
        log.info(e.getMessage());
        return new ErrorResponseEntity(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, e);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(AuthenticationException.class)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity wrongAuthentication(AuthenticationException e) {
        log.info(e.getMessage());
        return new ErrorResponseEntity(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that spring boot had some kind of locale config that would translate a good portion of the messages.

Comment: No, Spring too use external libraries, for example  your error message is generated by 'org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException' that has nothing to do with Spring Boot